# How coupa can be integrated to my asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, coupa

We have developed ecommerce website for client which doesn't have online payment option in that. Also site is made in such a way that one product have multiple qty range & pricing like below

1-10 - $30
11-50 - $27
$51-100 - $20

Here 1-10 is product qty & $30 is price per item. So if user selects qty 5 so it will charge price as $30/item. Once use place the order we receive order on our database & we fulfill it with offline payment. Client has requested to integrate coupa in this. Is it possible when there are multiple qty & price for single product.